# How do I align one li to the right and have a dropdown list down from it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Here is the webpage: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwYKQM

So I am a beginner web designer/programmer and I am just trying to make something to learn myself CSS and HTML (and JavaScript), but I seem to have a problem aligning the 'Archive' to the right of the list, beneath the search box and make the drop down list appear beneath the menu class and 'over' the main content area. I have tried floating it right, but the list element just 'floated' above the others a little. Also, when I hover above the main list

If you feel like it, please leave some advice to the look and the feel of the webpage and what I can do further. 

This is the CSS for the menu:

```
.menu {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
    float: right;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

.menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: As I see in the codepen link it works fine. I see a horizontal list when i hover, or do you want it in a vertical list?

Comment: I want it like it is, but the problem is that when I hover over the list to reveal the horizontal list, both the list and the horizontal list is selected, making it hard to use the buttons on the new horizontal list. Also, I want the 'Archives' to the far right of the menu element, and I can't seem to make it go there. Also, I do not want the menu element to extend to fit the new horizontal line.

Comment: Put your code what you have until now in a codepen or jsfiddle so I have a better view on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<html>
<header>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!--- Fontene brukt på nettstedet -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400,600,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta>
</header>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div id="header">
        <a href="#">Test<span>Page</span></a>
        <form action="" autocomplete="off">
          <input type="text" value="Search..." id="search" style="padding: 3px; color:#666"></input>
          <input type="button" value="Go!" style="display:none; padding: 3px;" id="searchBtn"></input>
        </form>
      </div>

<!--- 686px is min-width for desktop and tablet -->
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="rigthUL">
      <li>
          <a href="#" id="menu-item-left">Archive &or;</a>
          <ul class="underMenu">
            <li><a href="#">December</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">January</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">February</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">March</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">April</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  <div class="container-big">
    <div class="blogPost generalBox">
      <h2>blogTest</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, culpa dolorem veritatis, incidunt nobis quae fugiat. Ex architecto illo soluta obcaecati in cumque, est voluptas earum voluptatibus aliquid sequi neque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, quasi recusandae eius illum nisi, reprehenderit accusamus nam molestias blanditiis consequuntur, quisquam! Quibusdam fuga tenetur unde, neque repellendus, quae error sint?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.rigthUL {
  position: absolute;
  right: 203px; \\adjust according to your Page
  top: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
.menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  right: 203px;
  top: 85px;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxeKJy)

Comment: Just try to click on sub ul menu items! Its not working

Comment: @Eirenaios see it now :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was just the effect I was after!

Comment: @gloriousCatnip No probelm :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this css for last li

```
.menu ul li:last-child{
    float:right;
  text-align: right;
  display:inline;
}
```

See update here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwYKBq

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/myvrGP)**

HTML:

```
<div class="menu clearfix">
 <div class="image-left">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="image-right">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="menu-item-left">Archive &or;</a>...</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```